# Can I declare a method with arguments with unknown types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm building a bunch of functions that will make my core data calls a bit nicer, and not so bloated.

Lets say I have a method that looks like this:

```
- (NSArray*)retrieveDataFrom:(NSString *) name where:(NSString *) where is:(NSString *) is {

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ = '%@')", where, is];

   return [self retrieveDataFrom:name withPredicate:predicate];
}
```

and then sometimes I want to do something like this (for example):

```
[self retrieveDataFrom:@"table" where:@"id" is:int 2];
```

instead of this:

```
[self retrieveDataFrom:@"table" where:@"id" is:@"2"];
```

Is there a way to get a method to accept an argument without knowing its type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. You can declare the input as `NSObject *` so it can take a `NSString *` or a `NSNumber *`, but you're still stuck using `NSNumber`'s ugly syntax.

```
[self retrieveDataFrom:@"table" where:@"id" is:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

However, better syntax is coming soon in the form of [Clang Language Extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

When these land, you'll be able to write this instead:

```
[self retrieveDataFrom:@"table" where:@"id" is:@2];
```

At present, the LLVM website says these will be in llvm 4.0. The smart money says this will be in Xcode 4.4, but I doubt Apple is beholden to a statement on the LLVM website.

Comment: Ditto. I just wish they had a @null for [NSNull null] planned.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Beeing an NS type is enough for me. From there I can set up conversions from NSNumber to int, etc. I could also let it accept an NSDictionary, and within that store multiple values. I guess I was too tired to think of this last night. Thanks for the awesome answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `(id)` instead of `(NSString *)`

```
- (NSArray*)retrieveDataFrom:(NSString *) name where:(NSString *) where is:(id) is
```

Answer (score 1):

No. At best, you can let it accept any obj-c type by using `id`, but you cannot have an argument accept *any* type. The only exception is using varargs, but even there the method needs some way of knowing what type of argument to expect before it even looks at the argument (e.g. `printf`-style methods use the format string to figure out what the type of the argument is going to be).

If you use `id`, your method will look like

```
- (NSArray *)retrieveDataFrom:(NSString *)name where:(NSString *)where is:(id)is;
```

And your usage will look like

```
[self retrieveDataFrom:@"table" where:@"id" is:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

Or with the [new objective-c literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html),

```
[self retrieveDataFrom:@"table" where:@"id" is:@2];
```

Comment: I guess I also could do this. What exactly is the difference from using id and NSObject (or are they the same?)?

Comment: Just a note, NSObject is the root class that most other classes inherit and are subclassed from. id is just a pointer to an object. Objective-C is dynamically typed, so objects of type id are dynamically checked at run time to see if they support whatever messages you're passing them. Setting a type allows the compiler to check things for you before run time. In practice, they are similar, however, there is a big difference between the two.

Comment: @Filibustr: `NSObject` is the most common root class, but there's a second called `NSProxy`, and you're allowed to create others if you want. `id` is the generic "any object" pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Use (id)

```
- (NSArray*)retrieveDataFrom:(id) name where:(id) whereIs:(id)is {
  ...
}
```

or pass (NSArray*)

```
- (NSArray*)retrieveDataFrom:(NSArray*) params {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it just came to me I could use an NSArray or NSDict instead. I'll try all these answers tonight. :)